# Recurrence relation using generating functions to solve?

Tags: combinatorics

Consider the recurrence relation: $ a_n = −a_{n−1} + 6a_{n−2}, n ≥ 2, a_0 = 0, a_1 = 4.$

(a) Solve the recurrence relation by finding the characteristic
equation.
$r^2+r+6=0 \to (r+ \frac {1}{2})^2 +\frac{23}{4}=0 \to r= -\frac {1}{2}\pm i\frac{ \sqrt {23}}{2}$

$a_n^{(h)} =  (-\frac {1}{2}+ (i\frac{ \sqrt {23}}{2})^n + ( -\frac {1}{2}\ -(i\frac{ \sqrt {23}}{2}))^n$

$a_n =  c_1(-\frac {1}{2}+ (i\frac{ \sqrt {23}}{2})^n + c_2 ( -\frac {1}{2}\ -(i\frac{ \sqrt {23}}{2}))^n $

$a_0=0 =  c_1 + c_2 $

$a_1 =4=  c_1(-\frac {1}{2}+ (i\frac{ \sqrt {23}}{2}) + c_2 ( -\frac {1}{2}\ -(i\frac{ \sqrt {23}}{2}))$

(b) Solve the recurrence relation using the method of generating functions.

$ a_2 = −a_{1} + 6a_{0} $

$ a_3 = −a_{2} + 6a_{1} $

$ a_4 = −a_{3} + 6a_{2} $

i know im supposed to  multiple $a_1 $ by x etc but im not really sure how to do it... how do i know what $g(x)$='s?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $r^2+r-6$?It also factors nicely.

Comment: yes sorry im tired arithmetic becomes difficult  when im tired. my main question is part b anyway ill fix the top when i have a chance got class now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$G(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n$

$G(x) = a_0x^0 + a_1x^1 + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} a_nx^n$

$G(x) - 4x= + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (-a_{n-1} + 6a_{n-2})x^n$

$G(x) - 4x= -\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_{n-1}x^n + 6\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_{n-2}x^n$

$G(x) - 4x= -x\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + 6x^2\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_{n-2}x^{n-2}$

$G(x) - 4x= -x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n} + 6x^2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}$

$G(x) - 4x= -x(-0x^0 + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}) + 6x^2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}$

$G(x) - 4x= -xG(x) + 6x^2G(x)$

$G(x) =  \frac{4x}{1 + x - 6x^2} = \frac{4x}{ (1-2 x)(1+3 x)}$

Apply partial fraction decomposition to get:

$G(x) = \frac{4}{5}\left(\frac{1}{1-2 x} - \frac{1}{1+3 x} \right)$

$a_n = \frac{4}{5}(2^n - (-3)^n)$

Answer (score 3):

It is formally very easy, but dizzying sometimes:

Define

$$f(x)=\sum_0^\infty a_nx^n$$

Write the recurrence relation,

$$a_{n+2}=-a_{n+1}+6a_n$$

Multiply by $x^{n+2}$

$$a_{n+2}x^{n+2}=-a_{n+1}x^{n+2}+6a_nx^{n+2}$$

Sum

$$\sum_0^\infty a_{n+2}x^{n+2}=-\sum_0^\infty a_{n+1}x^{n+2}+\sum_0^\infty 6a_nx^{n+2}$$

Do things

$$\sum_2^\infty a_{n}x^{n}=-x\sum_1^\infty a_{n}x^{n}+6x^2\sum_0^\infty a_nx^n$$

$$\sum_0^\infty a_{n}x^{n}-a_1x-a_0=-x\sum_0^\infty a_{n}x^n+a_0x++6x^2\sum_0^\infty a_nx^n$$

Recover $f(x)$

$$f(x)-a_1x-a_0=-xf(x)+a_0x+6x^2f(x)$$

Isolate:

$$(6x^2-x-1)f(x)=-a_1x-a_0x-a_0$$

$$f(x)=-\frac{a_1x+a_0x+a_0}{6x^2-x-1}=-\frac{a_1x+a_0x+a_0}{6x^2-x-1}$$

We can get now $a_0=0$, $a_1=4$

$$f(x)=\frac{-4x}{(2x-1)(3x+1)}=\frac{-4}{5(2x-1)}+\frac{-4}{5(3x+1)}$$

$$f(x)=\frac{4}{5(1-2x)}-\frac{4}{5(1-(-3x))}$$

These can be expanded as the geometric series:

$$f(x)=\sum_0^\infty\frac 45(2x)^n-\sum_0^\infty\frac 45(-3x)^n$$

At last,

$$f(x)=\sum_0^\infty\frac{4}{5}(2^n-(-3)^n)x^n$$